# Flutter commit to git after alter library

Tags: git, flutter

Is there a way to commit flutter framework library to your git project?

My problem using flutter is when I do some code change to the framework, the change only being kept on local repository. I wish I could push it to the remote repository so my team dont have to make the change on their own PC.

The other solution that i thought could be possible is creating my own flutter framework version, and push this clone to my own repository. But I'm not sure if this way is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done usually through [`git submodules`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

[`flutter/website` issue 1845](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/1845) is about that:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/flutter/flutter ./vendor/flutter
```

Consider [`passsy/flutter_wrapper`](https://github.com/passsy/flutter_wrapper), a  shell script which downloads and executes the Flutter SDK with the exact version defined in your project respository. It encourages the idea that upgrading Flutter should happen per project, not per developer.

It will [do the `git submodule add` for you](https://github.com/passsy/flutter_wrapper/blob/fcecf2c84c61d4ab6f94b5d8bc8edd5f6ded6ab3/install.sh#L52-L65).